# Error when creating the fomular fields - (Compiled size: 3,585 characters)

Tags: salesforce

Getting this error:

```
Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data.Syntax error. Missing ')' (Related field: Formula)
```

When it checks the syntax for the exceeding the characters limit, the output is:

```
No syntax errors in merge fields or functions. (Compiled size: 3,585 characters)
```

Activities_Main_Category_P__c is a picklist, so this formula should not have any issues with compounding references to other formulas.

Any ideas why this formula is not working?

Here is the code!

```
CASE( Language__c ,
"",CASE( TEXT(  Activities_Main_Category_P__c    ) ,
"customer relationship","customer relationship",
"production of goods","production of goods",
"buying and selling","buying and selling",
"marketing","marketing",
"providing service","providing service",
"ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း","customer relationship",
"ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း","production of goods",
"ဝယ်ရောင်းလုပ်ခြင်း","buying and selling",
"စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း","marketing",
"ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း","providing service",
"unknown"
),"English",CASE(TEXT(Activities_Main_Category_P__c),
"customer relationship","customer relationship",
"production of goods","production of goods",
"buying and selling","buying and selling",
"marketing","marketing",
"providing service","providing service",
"ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း","customer relationship",
"ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း","production of goods",
"ဝယ်ရောင်းလုပ်ခြင်း","buying and selling",
"စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း","marketing",
"ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း","providing service",
"unknown"
),"Myanmar Unicode",CASE(TEXT(Activities_Main_Category_P__c),
"customer relationship","ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း",
"production of goods","ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း",
"buying and selling","တဆင့်ခံရောင်းဝယ်ခြင်း",
"marketing","စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း",
"providing service","ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း",
"ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း","ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း",
"ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း","ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း",
"ဝယ်ရောင်းလုပ်ခြင်း","ဝယ်ရောင်းလုပ်ခြင်း",
"စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း","စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း",
"ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း","ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း",
"unknown"
),"Myanmar Zawgyi",CASE(TEXT(Activities_Main_Category_P__c),
"customer relationship","ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း",
"production of goods","ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း",
"buying and selling","တဆင့်ခံရောင်းဝယ်ခြင်း",
"marketing","စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း",
"providing service","ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း",
"ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း","ဝယ်သူများနဲ့ဆက်ဆံခြင်း",
"ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း","ကုန်ပစ္စည်းထုတ်လုပ်ခြင်း",
"စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း","စျေးကွက်ချဲ့ထွင်ခြင်း၊ကြော်ငြာလုပ်ခြင်း",
"ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း","ဝန်ဆောင်မှုပေးခြင်း",
"unknown"),
""
)
```

I expected to be changing the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Texts for English and for blank are same, right? You can buy yourself some time by restructuring your CASE. Skip English and put the default as last, it'll be your fallback.

```
CASE(Language__c ,
    "Myanmar Unicode", (your stuff here),
    "Myanmar Zawgyi", (other stuff),
    (default and english here)
)
```

this should cut your size by 1/4.

Past that... the only difference is the `"ဝယ်ရောင်းလုပ်ခြင်း","ဝယ်ရောင်းလုပ်ခြင်း",` bit, right? Is this a genuine mistake and should this be in the Zawgyi part too?

Because maybe you need

```
IF(BEGINS(TEXT(Language__c), 'Myanmar'),
    do the translated CASE,
    do the English and default CASE
)
```

Comment: post your final solution, I'm curious and will happily upvote :) you can even mark it accepted so it's solved, disappears from the list